# Microsoft Interoperability PowerPoint

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop

I used Microsoft Office interoperability to create PowerPoint files. It's working fine on my development computer but not on my Homologation environment.

After, execution we use to encounter this error:

> Application_Error
>
> Website
>
> MESSAGE: Presentation (unknown member) : Invalid request.  PowerPoint could not open the file.

SOURCE: Microsoft Office PowerPoint 2007

Comment: check whether office is installed or not

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you installed all the required prerequsites before running the application. How did you deploy the software on another computers?

What line of code exactly fired the exception? Did you try to add any log statements?

You may find the following materials helpful:

- [How to use Automation to create and to show a PowerPoint 2002 presentation by using Visual C# .NET 2002](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/303718/)
- [C# app automates PowerPoint (CSAutomatePowerPoint)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSAutomatePowerPoint-b312d416)

Comment: I did all installation like  Pia redistributable 2013 , Microsoft office 2007 and i allowed my program to be executed. Now i can't save my file. I am trying with this code.    try

        {

            unePresentation.SaveAs(filePath, powerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsOpenDocumentPresentation, Office.MsoTriState.msoTriStateToggle);

        }

        catch (Exception ex)

        {

            log.Debug(ex.Message);

        }  thanks for your help

Comment: my error log is : Application_Error

Website

MESSAGE: Presentation (unknown member) : Invalid request.  PowerPoint could not open the file.

 

SOURCE: Microsoft Office PowerPoint 2007

Comment: Do you automate PowerPoint on the server side?

Comment: Hello, my PowerPoint presentation is generated from database. I'm using sql server

Comment: What file do you try to open? The error message states that you are trying to open the file, but the code shown above is for saving.

Comment: i am saving the file before to send it to the user. i see the error when i saving the file on the my test computer not on local. I think it's a configuration problems which  ?

Comment: String MyStr = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("B");

        MyStr = MyStr.Replace("{", String.Empty);

        MyStr = MyStr.Replace("}", String.Empty);

        MyStr = MyStr.Replace("-", String.Empty);

 

        string fileName = MyStr.Substring(0, 32) + ".odp";

        string path = Params.Get_String("PathToExport");

        string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, fileName);

 

 

        log.Debug("------------------------------------------------------------------*");

 

        log.Debug("filePath : " +  filePath );

        log.Debug("powerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsOpe

Comment: WHat is the actual parameter passed to the SaveAs method?

Comment: i am passing the file path, the type of document i like to have,  and the the font : unePresentation.SaveAs(filePath, powerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsOpenDocumentPresentation, Office.MsoTriState.msoTriStateToggle);

 

expression .SaveAs(Filename, FileFormat, EmbedFonts)

 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/ff746389.aspx

Comment: What is the actual values?

Comment: See my log:                     - filePath : D:\EXPORT\6f83ac910a93444398e677ca308971b2.odp

- powerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation  : ppSaveAsOpenDocumentPresentation

- Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue  : msoTrue